# Setting Keyframe Interval for H264 live video encoding

Tags: apache-flex, video, streaming, h.264

I am trying to build a video chat application using flex where i am using H264 video codec and RTMP protocol. In flex i see camera.setKeyFrameInterval() function where i can mention the key frame interval. But how much important is to specify key frame interval while encoding a live video for streaming and is it no that the H264 codec will take care this by itself ?

Answer (score 0):

For best quality, you should allow the encoder to insert keyframes on its own. It is a configurable option however for cases where you may have viewers joining a stream in progress, If the encoder is only setting a keyframe every 60 seconds, than a viewer will need to wait that long before seeing any video.

Comment: Hmm... got your point szatmary. But in situations like where you need  some adaptive mechanism to take care of your stream quality in which an external algorithm plays some role, how do you see the encoder itself taking the full control of setting the keyframe intervals ?